# An olympiad-like inequality

Tags: inequalities

I found this problem in my old paper :

> Let $f(x)$ be a convex function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\forall x>0$ we have $f(x)>0$ and $n\geq 3$ a natural number then we have :
>   $$\Big(f(1)^{f(1)}f(2)^{f(2)}\cdots f(n)^{f(n)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots + f(n)}}+\Big(f(1)f(2)\cdots f(n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq f(1)+f(n) $$

I try to use Jensen's inequality we have :

$$\ln\Big( \Big(f(1)^{f(1)}f(2)^{f(2)}\cdots f(n)^{f(n)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots + f(n)}} \Big)\leq \ln\Big(\frac{f^2(1)+f^2(2)+\cdots+f^2(n)}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)}\Big)$$

Remains to show this :

$$\ln\Big(\frac{f^2(1)+f^2(2)+\cdots+f^2(n)}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)}\Big)\leq \ln\Big(f(1)+f(n)-\Big(f(1)f(2)\cdots f(n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)$$

This last inequality is true for $f(x)=e^x$ but certainly not for $f(x)=x$

Furthermore this result recall me the Mercer's inequality (see [here](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/540923.Jensen-MercerKLP.pdf))

Finally If the function $f(x)$ is concave and positive the inequality of the beginning is reversed .

I think it's too hard for an maths competition but you can use the tools you want .

I prefer hints as answer.

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Comment: You said you found this inequality in a paper. Was it proved there? Can you share the paper and/or the proof?

Comment: I think maybe "paper" means competition exam paper? If so, this is not suitable for this site.

Comment: MSE is a right place for such type questions.

Comment: @user64494 It seems that the question is already posted there: [An olympiad-like inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3407087).

Comment: As pointed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407087/an-olympiad-like-inequality#comment7007923_3407087), this seems to be wrong for $f(x) = x$ and $n=2$.

Answer (score 5):

The statement at the end of the OP, that "*If the function $f(x)$ is concave and positive the inequality of the beginning is reversed*" seems to have a counterexample:

For $f(x)=x^{99/100}$ the inequality 
$$\Big(f(1)^{f(1)}f(2)^{f(2)}\cdots f(n)^{f(n)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots + f(n)}}+\Big(f(1)f(2)\cdots f(n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq f(1)+f(n)$$
is satisfied for $n=3$, but not for $n=4$ or larger. The violation is small, but within numerical accuracy:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := x^(1 - 1/100)

In[2]:= N[Table[Product[f[j]^f[j],{j, 1, n}]^(1/Sum[f[j],{j, 1, n}])
          +Product[f[j],{j,1,n}]^(1/n)-f[1]-f[n],{n,3,5}],10]

Out[2]= {0.001042561976, -0.001537906443, -0.005870494687}
```

"Out[2]" is the left-hand-side minus the right-hand-side of the inequality, for n=3,4,5.